# Can you create a reference type with BOOST_AUTO?

Tags: c++, boost

for example I want something like:

```
std::vector<double> v;

BOOST_AUTO(vref &,v);
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/typeof/tuto.html

> Both BOOST_TYPEOF and BOOST_AUTO strip top-level qualifiers. Therefore, to allocate for example a reference, it has to be specified explicitly:

```
string& hello()
{
    static string s = "hello";
    return s;
}

BOOST_AUTO(&s, hello());
```